# How to run selenium scripts outside Development Environment or Command prompt

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to run my selenium webdriver scripts outside Eclipse. Otherwise I want to run my scripts on selenium.

What are the prerequisites for this? I am using selenium with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse, go to File Export and generate and Executable JAR file. Then you can just double click that generated JAR file to execute the script.